# JSPDF/ html2canvas :- Page Contents At Bottom Getting Cut on Multiple Pages

Tags: reactjs, html-table, jspdf, html2canvas, react-component

Below is my Code where the html contents (input) are downloaded into pdf

i have a page in which my html controls are present and I'm trying to download the same html file on button click. the page download but some contents get cut off at bottom of the page while converting the html to pdf. I have used jspdf and html2canvas for this implementation.

```
const input = document.getElementById('print');
  const pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait',
    unit: 'pt',
    format: 'a4',
    compress:true,
  });

  //check for Screen dimensions
  let srcwidth = document.getElementById('print').scrollWidth;

  pdf
    .html(input, {
      margin: [55, 0, 40, -2],
      autoPaging: 'text',
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 595.26 / srcwidth, //595.26 is the width of A4 page
        scrollY: 0,
      },
    })
    .then(() => {
      const pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
      const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

      //loop to set header/ footer, style, alignment, text style to the page
      for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        pdf.rect(
          5,
          5,
          pdf.internal.pageSize.width - 13,
          pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 13,
          'S',
        );
        pdf.setPage(i);
        pdf.viewerPreferences({"FitWindow":true,"ViewArea":"MediaBox","ViewClip":"MediaBox" });
        var header = 'CSMM 5A - Vessel Cyber Security Self Assessment';
        var headerLine =
          '_________________________________________________________________________________';
        const footer = `Page ${i} of ${pageCount}`;
        var submitedDate =
          'Date Last Edited: ' +
          this.formatDateTime(this.state.vesselAssesementData.editedOn);

        // if (i > 1) {
        pdf
          .setFont('sans-serif', '', 'bold')
          .setFontSize(14)
          .text(header, 20, 25, { baseline: 'top' });
        pdf.addImage(kline, 'PNG', 530, 12, 35, 35);
        pdf.text(headerLine, 10, 38, { baseline: 'top' });
        // }

        pdf
          .setFont('Arial, sans-serif', '', 'normal')
          .setFontSize(9)
          .text(
            submitedDate,
            pageWidth / 6.5 - pdf.getTextWidth(submitedDate) / 2,
            pageHeight - 18,
            { baseline: 'bottom' },
          );

        pdf
          .setFont('Arial, sans-serif', '', 'normal')
          .setFontSize(9)
          .text(
            footer,
            pageWidth / 1.08 - pdf.getTextWidth(footer) / 2,
            pageHeight - 18,

            { baseline: 'bottom|right' },
          );
      }
      pdf.save(
        `${
          'VesselCyberSecuritySelfAssessmentReport_' +
          this.state.vesselAssesementData.uniqueId
        }.pdf`,
      );
```

Below is image attached where the issue occurs.

[this is multiple page which is created where the content alignment issue occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9gvd.png)

Solution for this ASAP will be very helpful.